# Problem enabling and focusing a text field at the same time

Tags: swiftui, combine

So I am working on a view where I want to have editable text which is only made editable via a button press.  So basically, when pressing the "edit" button, a text field should be made editable, and the focus should be sent to the text field.

Here's how I have attempted to implement this:

```
struct MyView: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    @FocusState var isEditing
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField("Text", text: $text)
                .disabled(!isEditing)
                .focused($isEditing)
            Spacer()
            
            Button(isEditing ? "Done" : "Edit") {
                isEditing.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So if I comment out the `.disabled` line, the focus behavior works as intended.  However when the disabled call is there, pressing the edit button does not enable or focus the text field.

My best guess is that maybe the field cannot be focused because it's initially disabled?

Is there any way to achieve this behavior?  I've also tried using a separate @State var for disabled and this has the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to separate `isEditing` from `isFocusOn`, then make `isFocusOn` depends on `isEditing` like this

**Updated by @sak request: change editing on focus**

```
struct MyView: View {
    @Binding var text: String = ""
    @State private var isEditing: Bool = false
    @FocusState var isFocusOn: Bool
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if isEditing {
                TextField("Text", text: $text)
                    .focused($isFocusOn)
                    .onAppear {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            isFocusOn = true
                        }
                    }
            } else {
                TextField("Text", text: $text)
                    .disabled(true)
            }
            Spacer()
            Button(isEditing ? "Done" : "Edit") {
                isEditing.toggle()
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: isFocusOn) { newValue in
            if !newValue { isEditing = false }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that we don't set `edit = true` when it's on focus, otherwise the `disabled` will be useless

Comment: What I lose here is, if I change the focus not by toggling the button (i.e. tapping on another focusable element) then the view is still in `isEditing == true`.  Is there any way to get it so that `isEditing` will toggle whenever `isFocused` is toggled, as well as the reverse?

Comment: i've updated my answer base on your request