# Cannot enable and focus text field at the same time

Tags: swiftui

This question is essentially the same as [Problem enabling and focusing a text field at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71369916/problem-enabling-and-focusing-a-text-field-at-the-same-time), but the answer isn't quite to my satisfaction.

I have the following code to both enable and focus a text field when a context menu button is tapped. However, the only way I can get it to work is by adding the same TextField view code twice and have it check `isDisabled` before the view is created. This seems like a SwiftUI bug but want to make sure there isn't something I'm missing. Any workarounds to make this code cleaner are very welcome even if there is a bug.

```
struct PassionRowView: View {
  @Binding var passion: Passion
  @State private var isDisabled = true
  @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool
  
  var body: some View {
    if (isDisabled) {
      TextField("", text: $passion.title)
        .disabled(isDisabled)
        .focused($isFocused)
        .contextMenu {
          Button {
            isDisabled = false
            isFocused = true
          } label: {
            Text("Change name")
          }
        }
        .onChange(of: isFocused) { isFocused in
          if !isFocused {
            isDisabled = true
          }
        }
    } else {
      TextField("", text: $passion.title)
        .disabled(isDisabled)
        .focused($isFocused)
        .contextMenu {
          Button {
            isDisabled = false
            isFocused = true
          } label: {
            Text("Change name")
          }
        }
        .onChange(of: isFocused ) { isFocused in
          if !isFocused {
            isDisabled = true
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```